# Use of undeclared identifier 'buffer' and Unused variable 'buffer'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

im getting a Use of undeclared identifier 'buffer' on  memcpy(buffer, &m_Text[index], m_Index - index); and return atof(buffer); and the Unused variable 'buffer' error on char buffer[32] = { 0 }; is there a way of fixing this ? many thanks

```
double GetNumber()
{
    SkipWhitespaces();

    int index = m_Index;
    while (isdigit(m_Text[m_Index])) m_Index++;
    if (m_Text[m_Index] == '.') m_Index++;
    while (isdigit(m_Text[m_Index])) m_Index++;

    if (m_Index - index == 0)


    char buffer[32] = { 0 };
    memcpy(buffer, &m_Text[index], m_Index - index);

    return atof(buffer);
}
```

Comment: i used the code from this website : http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2009/02/04/evaluating-expressions-part-2-parse-the-expression/

Comment: you had an incomplete copy. On the side that reads `if(m_Index - index == 0)
         throw ParserException("Number expected but not found!", m_Index);`

Comment: @user4581301 this still gave me the same error error

Comment: Unfortunately my answer will give the same error because it only explains why it happens. This makes for a pretty poor answer, so my apologies. I will update.

Comment: This doesn't have anything do with [tag:compiler-construction]. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: Note that you can get GCC to warn about this with `-Wall`, which you should always use at least on new projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's add a few extra braces to demonstrate what's going on

```
double GetNumber()
{
    SkipWhitespaces();

    int index = m_Index;
    while (isdigit(m_Text[m_Index])) 
    { // added brace
        m_Index++;
    } // added close brace.
    if (m_Text[m_Index] == '.') 
    { // added brace
        m_Index++;
    } // added close brace.
    while (isdigit(m_Text[m_Index]))
    { // added brace
        m_Index++;
    } // added close brace.

    if (m_Index - index == 0)
    { // added brace
        char buffer[32] = { 0 };
    } // added close brace.
    memcpy(buffer, &m_Text[index], m_Index - index);

    return atof(buffer);
}
```

As originally written, the `if` statement had no body, so it took the next line as the body. Because `char buffer[32] = { 0 };`  is the next line, it becomes part of the `if` and goes out of scope as soon as the `if` exits, no longer existing by the time `memcpy` tries to use it.

I strongly recommend always including all braces while learning. It helps prevent mistakes. You can omit them later if you want, but I've always found them more help than hindrance.

## Solution

Looking in on the original code from the source blog, I find

```
if(m_Index - index == 0) 
    throw ParserException("Number expected but not found!", m_Index);
```

not

```
if (m_Index - index == 0)
```

Add in the missing line (preferably along with with the omitted braces) and `char buffer[32] = { 0 };` will once again be in the correct scope.